# RAID0 Array fails to re-assemble after boot

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm

I have 2x 1TB drives that I'd like to assemble into a RAID0 array.  Using mdadm, I can create the array (and have it appear on the Launcher).  But, even though I add the output of

```
mdadm --detail --scan` to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

and I add the new `/dev/md0` information to the `fstab`, the array won't persist after rebooting.  I can re-create the array using

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

Some artifacts of the array remain, like the label, and mountpoint, but that's all.  Also, the `mdadm --detail --scan` and `lsblk` commands yield different UUIDs for the same, newly created volumes.  Is this important?

As a side note, it appears as though only root can create files on the newly created volume, though I'm sure this could be taken care of later with a chmod.

Any ideas as to why the array doesn't show back up after booting?